# Can I delete a message with Facebook API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I want to delete a specify message such as selected by user. But SDK returns "Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported delete request";

$mid = (message_id get by FQL);
$facebook->api('/'.$mid, 'delete');

Is there how to delete a message?
(Incidentally, an event can delete by this method.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issuing a POST to delete a message is not documented on the Graph API [Message](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/) page in the Developer Pages. Judging by the return message you received, deleting messages from 3rd party apps isn't supported by the API.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will pass up this function.

Answer (score 2):

*You can only delete messages/posts/photos created by your app only* (not just anyone selected by user)